# Easy Korean Poems for Beginners

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, resources, korean-culture

I just wonder if anyone could help me find few poems in Korean that are not too hard for a beginner like me. I believe it could help me improving my vocabulary and grammar usage.

(I've been learning Korean for 2 years and a half)

Thank you.

Comment: I had asked this same question on HelloTalk and got a handful of answers you might find helpful: https://hellotalk.com/m/MGywXDSbI4MKVD==?id=ZOxzDN

Comment: @ryanbrainard 감사합니다 :)

Comment: search for nursery rhymes (동요) on youtube. There are plenty of nursery rhyme karaoke, with 한글 as well as Romanised subtitles. From the video you can find out whether it's about vegetable names, animal names, counting, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Okay, while @ting-choe has my gratitude for something that may level me up (my wife says I will "never understand" 김소월의 진달래꽃 - I think some "easier" poems (for my level) are in order here (and my Korean wife can recite these, too, so they must not be random).

```
**산토끼**
산토끼 토끼야 어디를 가느냐
깡총깡총 뛰면서 어디를 가느냐

산고개 고개를 나혼자 넘어서
토실토실 알밤을 주워 올테야

**닭**
귀여운 꼬마가 닭장에 가서
암탉을 잡으려다 놓쳤다네
닭장 밖에 있던 배고픈 여우
옳거니 하면서 물고갔다네

꼬꼬댁 암탉 소리를 쳤네
꼬꼬댁 암탉 소리를 쳤네
귀여운 꼬마가 그 꼴을 보고
웃을까 울을까 망설였다네


**코끼리 아저씨**
코끼리 아저씨는 코가 손이래
과자를 주면은 코로 받지요

코끼리 아저씨는 소방수요
불나면 빨리와 모셔가지요

**우리집 강아지**
1우리집 강아지는 복슬강아지
어머니가 시장가면 멍멍멍
촐랑촐랑 따라가며 멍멍멍
2우리집 강아지는 예쁜강아지
학교갔다 돌아오면 멍멍멍
꼬리치고 반갑다고 멍멍멍

**고기잡이**
고기를 잡으러 바다로 갈까나
고기를 잡으러 강으로 갈까나
이병에 가득히 넣어가지고서
라라라라 라라라라 온다나

선생님 모시고 가고싶지마는
하는 수 있나요 우리만 가야지
하는 수 있나요 우리만 가야지
라라라라 라라라라 간다나

**옹달샘**
깊은산속 옹달샘 누가와서 먹나요
맑고 맑은 옹달샘 누가와서 먹나요
새벽에 토끼가 눈비비고 일어나
세수하러 왔다가 물만먹고 가지요

**다람쥐**
산골짝에 다람쥐 아기 다람쥐
도토리 점심가지고 소풍을 간다
다람쥐야 다람쥐야 재주나 한 번 넘으렴
파알딱 파알딱 팔딱 날도 참말 좋구나

**곰 세 마리**  <-- this one is awesome, my kids used to sing it!
곰 세 마리가 한 집에 있어
아빠곰 엄마곰 애기곰
아빠곰은 뚱뚱해

엄마곰은 날씬해
애기곰은 너무 귀여워
으쓱으쓱 잘한다

**개구리**
개굴개굴 개구리 노래를 한다
아들 손자 며느리 다 모여서
밤새도록 하여도 듣는 이 없네
듣는 사람 없어도 날이 밝도록
개굴개굴 개구리 노래를 한다
개굴개굴 개구리 목청도 좋다

**송아지**
송아지 송아지 얼룩송아지
엄마소도 얼룩소 엄마 닮았네

**아기돼지**
토실토실 아기돼지 젖달라고 꿀꿀꿀
엄마돼지 오냐오냐 알았다고 꿀꿀꿀
꿀꿀 꿀꿀 꿀꿀 꿀꿀
꿀꿀꿀꿀 꿀꿀꿀꿀 꿀꿀꿀꿀꿀
아기돼지 바깥으로 나가자고 꿀꿀꿀
엄마돼지 비가와서 안된다고 꿀꿀꿀

텔레비전에 내가 나왔으면
텔레비전에 내가 나왔으면
정말 좋겠네 정말 좋겠네
춤추고 노래하는 예쁜 내 얼굴
텔레비전에 내가 나왔으면
정말 좋겠네 정말 좋겠네

**솜사탕**
나뭇가지에 실처럼 날아든 솜사탕
하얀눈처럼 희고도 깨끗한 솜사탕
엄마손잡고 나들이갈때 먹어본 솜사탕
훅훅 불면은 구멍이 뚫리는 커다란 솜사탕

**싹트네**
싹트네 싹터요 내 마음에 사랑이
싹트네 싹터요 내 마음에 사랑이
밀려오는 파도처럼 내 마음에 사랑이
싹트네 싹터요 내 마음에 사랑이

**짝짜꿍**
엄마 앞에서 짝짜꿍 아빠 앞에서 짝짜꿍
엄마 한숨은 잠자고 아빠 주름살 펴져라
```

Comment: Hahaha. This is really preschool poems for children. I think these are good to study korean language.

Comment: And most of them are  actually songs.

Comment: @tingchoe 으쓱으쓱 잘한다! i can hear the tune now!

Answer (score 9):

진달래꽃 - 김소월

나 보기가 역겨워
가실 때에는
말없이 고이 보내 드리우리다

영변에 약산
진달래꽃
아름 따다 가실 길에 뿌리우리다

가시는 걸음 걸음
놓인 그 꽃을
사뿐히 즈려밟고 가시옵소서

나 보기가 역겨워
가실 때에는
죽어도 아니 눈물 흘리우리다

If someone doesn't know this poem, he or she is not South Korean.

Here is a link to the translation for this poem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Sowol

Comment: +1 that i started reading this and my wife (korean) who was not looking at the computer started reciting faster than i could read it off the page! i think i'm going to have to memorize this - thank you!

Comment: Is there a link to the translation for this poem, or it's cultural significance?

Comment: @Amacelia I edited. You can refer.

Comment: I am very against this answer, because although it is a very beatufiul one, the vocabulary and grammer used in this poem are quite archaic, some even no longer used in 21th century spoken or written Korean except in very restricted context. '아름', '-우리다', '즈리-', '-옵소서' ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check out the following famoun Korean poem:

> 서시 - 윤동주
>
> 죽는 날까지 하늘을 우러러 한 점 부끄럼이 없기를,
>
> 잎새에 이는 바람에도 나는 괴로워했다.
>
> 별을 노래하는 마음으로
>
> 모든 죽어 가는 것을 사랑해야지.
>
> 그리고 나한테 주어진 길을 걸어가야겠다.
>
> 오늘 밤에도 별이 바람에 스치운다.

Here's the link with the meaning the title + poem in English: [서시 - 윤동주](https://tonysweb.biz/song_poem/work/foreword.html)

Here is another poem by the same poet, which is also very famous: [별 헤는 밤 - 윤동주](https://tonysweb.biz/song_poem/work/a-night-of-counting-the-stars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Under there is 70 poem which many Korean loves.
My favorite Korean poem is "빼앗긴 들에도 봄은 오는가?"
This poem is written about Japanese colonial period.

지금은 남의 땅 ― 빼앗긴 들에도 봄은 오는가? ---- 이상화 (Lee sang hwa)

나는 온 몸에 햇살을 받고
푸른 하늘 푸른 들이 맞붙은 곳으로
가르마 같은 논길을 따라 꿈 속을 가듯 걸어만 간다.

입술을 다문 하늘아 들아
내 맘에는 나 혼자 온 것 같지를 않구나
네가 끌었느냐 누가 부르더냐 답답워라 말을 해 다오.

바람은 내 귀에 속삭이며
한 자국도 섰지 마라 옷자락을 흔들고
종조리는 울타리 너머 아씨같이 구름 뒤에서 반갑다 웃네.

고맙게 잘 자란 보리밭아
간밤 자정이 넘어 내리던 고운 비로
너는 삼단 같은 머리를 감았구나 내 머리조차 가뿐하다.

혼자라도 가쁘게나 가자.
마른 논을 안고 도는 착한 도랑이
젖먹이 달래는 노래를 하고 제 혼자 어깨춤만 추고 가네.

나비 제비야 깝치지 마라
맨드라미 들마꽃에도 인사를 해야지
아주까리 기름을 바른 이가 지심 매던 그 들이라 다 보고 싶다.

내 손에 호미를 쥐여 다오
살진 젖가슴과 같은 부드러운 이 흙을
발목이 시도록 밟아도 보고 좋은 땀조차 흘리고 싶다.

강가에 나온 아이와 같이
짬도 모르고 끝도 없이 닫는 내 혼아
무엇을 찾느냐 어디로 가느냐 웃어웁다 답을 하려무나.

나는 온 몸에 풋내를 띠고
푸른 웃음 푸른 설움이 어우러진 사이로
다리를 절며 하루를 걷는다 아마도 봄 신령이 지폈나 보다.

그러나 지금은 ― 들을 빼앗겨 봄조차 빼앗기겠네.

https://leftwritelit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Daum-70-Representative-Korean-Poets.pdf